# Common Mode Differential Analog Input

Tags: analog, signal, pnp, common-mode

I'm using the LTC5598 IC for modulation. I am confused as to how to properly feed my BaseBand analog signal into the chip.

According to its [datasheet](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/5598f.pdf):

> The circuit is optimized for a common mode voltage of 0.5V which
>   should be externally applied. The baseband pins should not be left
>   floating because the internal PNP’s base current will pull the common
>   mode voltage higher than the 0.6V limit. This condition may damage the
>   part. In shut-down mode, it is recommended to have a termination to
>   ground or to a 0.5V source with a value lower than 1kΩ. The PNP’s base
>   current is about –68μA in normal operation.

[image]

If I understand this correctly, if I want to feed it an instantaneous signal of 0.4V do I set:

```
BBPI = 0.9V
BBMI = 0.5V
```

This should satisfy the requirement of having a common mode voltage (Vcmbb) of 0.5V?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit more complicated than that. Have you seen the example driver filter circuit?

It's designed to be driven by a *differential* signal, centered on 0.5V. The datasheet talks about a swing of 0V to 1V. That should be your swing. So a 40% amplitude wave should have a peak at (0.5*0.4) + 0.5 on the positive rail and -(0.5*0.4) + 0.5 on the negative rail.

Additionally you need to provide a suitably terminated driver. The "negative input impedance" is a bit weird, but what it means is that the inputs will run away and self-destruct unless their bias current goes somewhere. The datasheet says "it is reccomended to have termination to ground or 0.5V through a resistor less than 1k", and indeed their example driver filter terminates to ground through a 100 ohm resistor.

(Why is the filter there? It's there to round off the edges of your signal coming from the DAC in order that it modulates cleanly).

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense. Yes, I did see the example driving circuit, however, it seems to be driven by current. I wanted to drive via a voltage based ADC

Comment: Which DAC did you have in mind? Picking one with differential outputs is pretty much required.

Comment: Understood. I guess I will use a Balun (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balun)

Comment: Where's the signal coming from, ultimately? Could you just choose a different DAC?

Comment: Yes, i can choose a different dac. Actually, the source would be a microcontroler with a 10-bit dac. But, my baseband with bee purly digital. It will be either +0.4V or -0.4V. So I am now thinking about doing it without a DAC, and through OP-amps with built in LPF

Answer (score 1):

No, you have to be balanced; a 0.5V offset means BBPI = 0.7V and BBMI = 0.3V. The average of the two is still 0.5V. Having said that don't overdrive them too much either. The spec say these inputs can be run at 0.86Vp-p (page 4) and that voltage is superimposed on the 0.5V BUT remember they shouldn't be driven single ended or damage may occur.

At the peak of the 0.86Vp-p, one input will have 0.93V and the other will have 0.07V. Both average at 0.5V.